# Very slow View and column name lagged behind after new update 1.1.453

Tags: r, ide, rstudio

I updated my Rstudio to Version 1.1.453. After I updated it, "View" became so slow and column names are always way lag behind side scrolling. Vertical scrolling takes some seconds to show which way slower than the previous version. note that my table is 10000*40.
The problem is even worse in Modern Theme and Sky Theme (Classic Theme works better).
It used to work faster in the old version.
(I am using mac os 10.13.5).
Is there any way that I can fix this issue?

Comment: Might be worth asking here: https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: I've resorted to `View(head(dat, 100))` now because of these issues